# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException library works in test but not in main

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception

I have a very frustrating library issue, it is seen by my test class but not by my src/main/java class. It compiles but throws the error at runtime.

I tried everything for the build classpath without luck.

tried including external jar but maven wanted the dependency so added it as below. The test class runs fine, but the main class throws the error not seeing the class at runtime.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ireasoning</groupId>
      <artifactId>snmpv3</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.05</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>C:/Users/jokrasa/jars/ireasoningtl1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Has anyone else seen such issues ?

Comment: Have you tried changing scope to `<scope>compile</scope>`?

Comment: how are you running the jar file? Is the classpath set?

Comment: Check your runtime classpath rather than your compilation classpath. These can be necessarily different.

Comment: @Frederico  how do you refer to the jar in compile scope ?